# Adding background image in HTML5 Boilerplate

Tags: css, html, html5boilerplate

I've recently downloaded html5 boilerplate and trying to get a good grasp on how to incorporate my css codes in side of the main.css of html5 boilerplate. I need to know how can I add my background image to my page?

```
  html {
    background:url(Images/laptop.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
body {
  background-image:url(../Images/laptop.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  // rest of your code
}
```

Your CSS file should be in the `css` folder and image should be in a different folder. Therefore, I used `../` before the path.

**Here is a brief description of the file paths:**

`./` means the current directory

`../` means the parent of the current directory, not the root directory

`/` is the root directory

`myfile.text` is in the current directory, as is `./myfile.text`

`../myfile.text` is one level above you and `/myfile.text` lives in your root directory.